# Disable Breadcrumbs in Joomla 4

Tags: css, joomla, breadcrumbs, joomla4

I recently upgraded my site to Joomla 4 and noticed that the breadcrumb appears on all pages. I looked in the module settings, but I can't find a module for the breadcrumb.

I have a custom template, I don't use cassiopeia.

I also checked my template settings, but I can't find an option to disable the breadcrumb there.

Can anyone guide me on how to disable the breadcrumb in Joomla 4? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

I tried to disable breadcrumb through the module settings in the Joomla admin panel. I expected to find a module called "Breadcrumb" that I could simply disable. However, I could not find a module with that name.

I also checked the settings of my active template, looking for an option to disable breadcrumb, but could not find anything like that.

I expected there to be a simple option to disable the breadcrumb, since it is a common feature in content management systems. I am looking for a solution that will allow me to disable the breadcrumb on all pages of my Joomla 4 site.

Comment: Do you have your joomla site url at least ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the site is in a testing environment not visible from the outside; did you have something in mind?

Comment: You could hide it with CSS but you would need to give use at least the html structure

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to "Site Modules" page at the backend
2. Filter module by type "Breadcrumbs"
3. If not found, check hardcode of the default template